# MySQLdb: correct SQL request to group response data

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have two simple tables: authors and articles. You can find it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e765f3).

So when I execute MySQLdb query:

```
import MySQLdb
def test_code():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(mysql_host, mysql_user, mysql_pass, mysql_base)
    db.query("select * from `authors` join `articles` on articles.`authorId` = authors.`id`")
    r = db.store_result()
    result = ()
    while True:
        row = r.fetch_row(how=1)
        if row:
            result += row
        else:
            return result
print test_code()
```

I got the following results:

```
({
    'firstname': 'Alexandro',
    'Title': 'My life',
    'lastname': 'Riviera',
    'articles.id': 6L,
    'authorId': 1L,
    'id': 1L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Alexandro',
    'Title': 'My life 2',
    'lastname': 'Riviera',
    'articles.id': 7L,
    'authorId': 1L,
    'id': 1L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Helen',
    'Title': 'Learn SQL',
    'lastname': 'Oldgarno',
    'articles.id': 8L,
    'authorId': 2L,
    'id': 2L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Helen',
    'Title': 'SQL for you',
    'lastname': 'Oldgarno',
    'articles.id': 9L,
    'authorId': 2L,
    'id': 2L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Joe',
    'Title': 'Python',
    'lastname': 'Smith',
    'articles.id': 10L,
    'authorId': 3L,
    'id': 3L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Joe',
    'Title': 'Python 2',
    'lastname': 'Smith',
    'articles.id': 11L,
    'authorId': 3L,
    'id': 3L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Joe',
    'Title': 'Python 3',
    'lastname': 'Smith',
    'articles.id': 12L,
    'authorId': 3L,
    'id': 3L
})
```

instead of this I would like to get articles of athor in a dictionary where the author is, something like:

```
({
    'id': 1L,
    'firstname': 'Alexandro',
    'lastname': 'Riviera',
    'articles': [{
        'Title': 'My life',
        'articles.id': 6L
    }, {
        'Title': 'My life 2',
        'articles.id': 7L
    }]
},

{
    'id': 2L,
    'firstname': 'Helen',
    'lastname': 'Oldgarno',
    'articles': [{
        'Title': 'Learn SQL',
        'articles.id': 8L
    }, {
        'Title': 'SQL for you',
        'articles.id': 9L,
    }],
})
```

Is it possible to get such results with correct SQL request OR I need to do it "by hands" in a python-way?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: mysql queries will not return "nested" structures like that. You'll have to take the "flat" returns from mysql and do that yourself.

Comment: I was expecting this :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you answered your own question: MySQL (and many others) aren't the best solution for custom formatting. Using a scripting language to read the results of the query, then format to your desired look/feel, is the proper approach.