# Combine dict with same keys into one dict with list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a tuple of dicts, that I receive as answer from mysql server.

```
({
    'firstname': 'Alexandro',
    'Title': 'My life',
    'lastname': 'Riviera',
    'articles.id': 6L,
    'authorId': 1L,
    'id': 1L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Alexandro',
    'Title': 'My life 2',
    'lastname': 'Riviera',
    'articles.id': 7L,
    'authorId': 1L,
    'id': 1L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Helen',
    'Title': 'Learn SQL',
    'lastname': 'Oldgarno',
    'articles.id': 8L,
    'authorId': 2L,
    'id': 2L
}, {
    'firstname': 'Helen',
    'Title': 'SQL for you',
    'lastname': 'Oldgarno',
    'articles.id': 9L,
    'authorId': 2L,
    'id': 2L
})
```

and I would like to transform by same keys "authorId" into:

```
({
    'firstname': 'Alexandro',
    'lastname': 'Riviera',
    'id': 1L,
    'articles': [{
        'articles.id': 6L,
        'authorId': 1L,
        'Title': 'My life'
    }, {
        'articles.id': 7L,
        'authorId': 1L,
        'Title': 'My life 2'
    }]
}, {
    'firstname': 'Helen',
    'lastname': 'Oldgarno',
    'id': 2L,
    'articles': [{
        'articles.id': 8L,
        'authorId': 2L,
        'Title': 'Learn SQL'
    }, {
        'articles.id': 9L,
        'authorId': 2L,
        'Title': 'SQL for you'
    }]
})
```

I have no idea how to complete this task in not really ugly way. Any suggestions will be helpful!

Comment: Perhaps this question (and its answers) may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a merge function like this, but you really should consider rewriting your SQL query. Here is a simple solution:

```
def merge_books(books):
    merged = {}

    for book in books:
        authorId = book['authorId']

        # Create article attribute
        book['articles'] = [{
            'articles.id': book['articles.id'],
            'authorId':    book['authorId'],
            'Title':       book['Title'],
        }]

        # Remove redundant information
        del book['articles.id']
        del book['authorId']
        del book['Title']

        if authorId in merged:
            merged[authorId]['articles'].append(book['articles'][0])
        else:
            merged[authorId] = book

    # Convert dict into a tuple, but why not a list?
    return tuple(merged.values())
```

A better way would be to use two select statements and merge their results together:

```
import MySQLdb

def get_authors_with_articles(connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    authors = {}
    for author in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Authors'):
        # Initialize empty article list that will be popluated with the next select
        author['articles'] = []
        authors[author['id']] = author

    for article in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Articles').fetchall():
        # Fetch and delete redundant information
        author_id = article['authorId']
        del article['authorId']

        authors[author_id]['articles'].append(article)

    return list(authors.values())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(
        mysql_host,
        mysql_user,
        mysql_pass,
        mysql_base,
        cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor
    )
    print(get_authors_with_articles(connection))
```

Comment: Well, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494199/mysqldb-correct-sql-request-to-group-response-data) is why I ask. My SQL query is simple:)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it into a list and sort by authorID.  Once you're able to separate them based on authorID you can definitely collapse the author information fields and put the article information into a list.